# Imacro go to next pages of reults to extract data?

Tags: web-scraping, imacros

I want to extract data from linkein result page. I need to go next pages, one by one until last page of results.

I read all the docs:
http://wiki.imacros.net/FAQ#How_do_I_loop_through_multiple_pages_of_results.3F

http://wiki.imacros.net/FAQ#Q:_How_to_create_nested_loops.3F

But it is too complicate for me.

So I searched for similaire problem with linkedin, but nothing with my case. All problem are custom.

So I am asking here help if some expert Imacro could tell me which lines of code to add in my script to go to next page result.

here is my actual script:

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?   keywords=gestionnaire%20de%20patrimoine&trk=tyah&trkInfo=clickedVertical%3Aautocomplete,clickedEntityId%3A1,idx%3A1-1-1,tarId%3A1466679830045,tas%3Agestionaire%20de%20patrimoine&rsid=1951573471466679858087&openFacets=N,G,CC&orig=FCTD&f_G=fr%3A0&page_num=5&pt=people
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Suivant<SP>>
TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:fa<SP>fa-square&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>email<SP>addresses<SP>&    <SP>save<SP>leads
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Suivant<SP>>
```

Does anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can go to the next page results by means of the code like this:

```
SET !LOOP 1
URL GOTO=https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?keywords=gestionnaire%20de%20patrimoine&trk=tyah&trkInfo=clickedVertical%3Aautocomplete,clickedEntityId%3A1,idx%3A1-1-1,tarId%3A1466679830045,tas%3Agestionaire%20de%20patrimoine&rsid=1951573471466679858087&openFacets=N,G,CC&orig=FCTD&f_G=fr%3A0&page_num={{!LOOP}}&pt=people
```

Just play it in loop mode and make sure that it works.